# Ruby .each with removal of items in collection

Tags: c#, ironruby

I am currently working with an app that allows for runtime addition and removal of items in a drop down list via a rub script.  The Ruby looks like this

```
SAFE = ;
return control if control.CyclesCount == 0;
control.Items.each{|item| control.Items.Remove(item) if item.Value.index('|').nil?};
return control;
```

control is  custom user control and its Items is a ListItemCollction.  I am running via unit tests to get my Ruby code correct and running into some trouble.  The ListItemColletion I am passing in looks like this ..

```
var lic = new ListItemCOllection {
  new ListItem {Text = "Item2", Value = "8"}, 
  new ListItem {Text = "Item1", Value = "1"},
  new ListItem {Text = "Item3", Value = "3|1"},
  new ListItem {Text = "Item4", Value = "4"},
  new ListItem {Text = "Item5", Value = "5|2"},
  new ListItem {Text = "Item6", Value = "6"}
}
```

Instead of leaving the 2 items with the pipe in them, this code always seems to leave 3 items in the items collection.  The 3 depend on the order that I put the items in (while in this order, Item1, Item3, Item5 get left)which leads me to believe that its the remove that is messed up.  I have also tried to take a copy of the collection, loop through it, removing from the original so that I was not removing from the collection I was iterating through.  I am a relatve noob to Ruby so go easy on me ... but I could use some advice.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. Are you talking about IronRuby or something? I'd tag it as such cause thats not like any native Ruby code I know.

Comment: you're correct, sorry, it was mis-tagged.  Should be iron ruby not ruby.  I will try and figure out how to change that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not advisable to change an array while iterating over it. There are some Iterators whose purpose is to change the array.

```
a= [1,2,3]
b= [1,2,3]
a.delete_if { |x| x == 2 } # => [1,3]
b.reject! { |x| x == 2 } # => [1,3]
a # => [1,3]
b # => [1,3]
```

`Array#delete_if` deletes elements of an array. There is only a minor difference to `Array#reject`

```
a= [1,2,3]
b= [1,2,3]
a.delete_if { |x| false } # => [1,3]
b.reject! { |x| false } # => nil
a # => [1,2,3]
b # => [1,2,3]
```

`Array#delete_if` always returns the remaining array. `Array#reject!` returns nil instead in case the array remains unchanged.

Some more modifiieng iterators which, do not change the original array:

```
a= [1,2,3]
a.reject { |x| x == 2 } # => [1,3]
a # => [1,2,3]
```

`Array#reject` returns an array without the rejected elements, but does not modify the original array.

```
a= [1,2,3]
a.select { |x| x != 2 } # => [1,2,3]
a # => [1,3]
```

`Array#select` returns an array of only the selected elements, but does not modify the original array.

Comment: delete_if got me what I needed.

Comment: based on the comments from Jorg I asked if there was a reason to try and get th Reject to work over delete_if ... just waiting on the response till I accepted the answer

Comment: `Array#delete_if` and `Array#reject!` are mostly the same.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying a collection *while* you are iterating through it is *never* a good idea. If you do that, all hell breaks loose. (Preferably, it would raise some kind of exception, but that's life ...)

However, that's not actually the biggest problem in your code. The biggest problem is that you have commited the mortal sin of Ruby: not knowing `Enumerable`. (Don't worry: everybody commits that sin. All the time.)

If you want to reject all elements from a collection that satisfy a condition, there's a method for that, and it's called exactly what you would expect: `Enumerable#reject!`.

So, let's clean this up, shall we?

```
SAFE = ;
```

What's that semicolon doing there? It seems you got your C# and Ruby mixed up :-)
(Oh, and also, that line doesn't do anything useful anyway, does it?)

```
return control if control.CyclesCount == 0;
```

Again, useless semicolon.

```
control.Items.each{|item| control.Items.Remove(item) if item.Value.index('|').nil?};
```

This is where it gets interesting:

```
control.Items.reject! {|item| item.Value.include?('|') }
```

Much better, isn't it?

```
return control;
```

I personally like to reserve the `return` keyword for "pure" methods (i.e. methods that don't have side-effects), so I wouldn't use one here since the code modifies `control.Items` but that is a style choice. Putting it all together, this is how I would write it:

```
return control if control.cycles_count == 0
control.items.reject! {|item| item.value.include?('|') }
control
```

Note: I don't have a working install of IronRuby right now, so I am making a few assumptions that I can unfortunately not test:

- method name transliteration (`CyclesCount` -> `cycles_count`) works,
- `Value` is some kind of `String` or collection and
- `ListItemCollection` mixes in `Enumerable`

The latter *should* be the case if `ListItemCollection` implements `IEnumerable` (otherwise I would consider that a bug in IronRuby). If `ListItemCollection` does *not* implement `IEnumerable` (which I would probably consider a bug in `ListItemCollection`), that is still easily fixed:

```
class ListItemCollection; include Enumerable end
```

[BTW: I would also introduce a `cycles?` method (or a `bool HasCycles` property on the .NET side), so that you can get rid of the `cycle_count == 0` test.]

Comment: SAFE = was a typo, should be SAFE = 1, and it is my understanding that it is safer depending on the data used "Ruby disallows the use of tainted data by potentially dangerous operations".  As for the semi colons, I pulled that code from my c# unit tests and just didn't clean it up.  I would like to use the reject, but it generates a new collection of a different type. I just coded the delete_if and it seems to work ..any reason not to?  And thanks for the info.  Benefits to include? over index?

Comment: Ah, you mean `$SAFE = 1`! Actually, I'm not sure that this does anything. AFAIK, IronRuby doesn't implement `$SAFE` levels (although maybe it *does* implement `$SAFE` level 1). Anyway, you only need this if you execute arbitrary code from untrusted users. (And if you *do* execute untrusted code, then you need a whole lot more than just `$SAFE = 1`.) As for why I'm using `include?`: because that's the question you are asking. I had to read that line several times to figure out that what you *really* wanted to know was whether `Value` contains a vertical bar. So why not write that down?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove items from an array based on a condition, you should use [`Array#reject!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002197):

```
control.Items.reject! {|item| item.Value.index('|').nil? };
```

In order to properly debug this, however, we need to know what `control.Items` looks like on the Ruby end.